# Editable subitems within a ListView

Tags: c#, listview

I have a `ListView` similar to this:

```
Name | Pass | Proxy | Keyword
Usr1 | pass1| 88.x..| stackoverflow
Usr2 | pass2| 78.x..| google
```

I want the user to be able to double click on for example Google, and be able to update it to something else. Right now the user has to remove the entire row and add a new updated one in order to achieve this.

I've tried searching for I cannot seem to find any easy solution to this problem. Any and all help is very welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ObjectListView: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

It provides the functionality you need, and is quite easy to use and set-up. I'd recommend reading the documentation on it, as it's not a plug-and-play replacement for the .Net ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can make listviewitems editable. I believe it's a property on the listview itself.

LabelEdit is the property. You can catch the change in the corresponding events.